# Probability of not happening an event in some years, if probability of it happening in a minute is given

Tags: probability, reliability

I came across a problem for which I found two answers and I don't know which is the correct one.

> At a particular site, the probability of occurrence of moderate earthquake in a single minute is assumed to be $10^{-8}$. If the events in succeeding minutes are statistically independent, what is the probability that there will be no moderate earthquake during the 50 year life of the building.

Probability of occurrence of moderate earthquake in a minute $=10^{-8}$

**Answer 1:**
Probability of occurrence of moderate earthquake in 50 years
$=10^{-8}\times60\times24\times365\times50=0.2628$
(*Ignoring leap years*)
Probability that there will be no moderate earthquake in 50 years,
$=1-0.2628=0.7372$

**Answer 2:**
Probability that there will be no moderate earthquake in a minute
$=1-10^{-8}$
Probability that there will be no moderate earthquake in 50 years,
$=(1-10^{-8})^{60\times24\times365\times50}=0.7689$

Both answers are pretty close, but which is the correct answer?

Comment: For your attempt at answer 1, consider what happens if you were to ask the question instead for $500$ years rather than $50$.  What "*probability*" do you get?  Is that possible?

Comment: Do not confuse *expected number of earthquakes* with *probability of earthquake*

Comment: So answer 2 is the correct one?

Comment: Yes.  Also, if you want to account for leapyears a bit better in your calculation, you can use that there are $365.2425$ days per year on average

Comment: Thanks! Your help meant a lot.